# AppCode - Is it possible to show the current function name?

Tags: jetbrains-ide, appcode

While navigating through a huge code base and finding oneself inside some arbitrary function, it's sometimes not obvious which function that actually is.

Xcode always shows the current function name at the top of the editor. Is that also possible in AppCode?

Comment: Breadcrumbs may not yet be implemented (not AppCode user): https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/OC-8692 and https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/OC-13965 . See possible workarounds (at least something) in this comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/OC-8692#comment=27-613671

Comment: There actually is a Breadcrumbs option in the settings...and this is exactly what I want...but it just doesn't show in my code. Neither in Objective-C nor in C++ (which I mainly use). Maybe there's something else wrong?

Comment: Also big thanks for this context info shortcut. That's really something! It should stay on screen always, but it's much better than scrolling all the time.

Comment: Breadcrumbs are only available in IntelliJ-based IDEs for a limited set of languages, not including objc-c or C++ IIRC.

Comment: Yeah, it's weird that the setting is available in AppCode though - since it's only used for Objective-C, Swift and C++

Comment: It is a bit weird, but not totally unreasonable as plenty of macOS/iOS projects contain javascript, html, json etc all of which have breadcrumb support. Shame there's nothing for swift or objective-c yet.

Comment: Ah I see, that's understandable. Then at the very least it would be great to just show the current function for the other languages there instead. Just show what this hotkey 'context info' can do at the top if breadcrumbs are enabled. That would already greatly enhance the workflow